# save data from php to ajax and change color of div when new data insert?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi i am trying to save   value and alert them using ajax which i am insert using php in my sql table but my alert is not working

Here is my code
**demo.php**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function my(){
             var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
         var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
      document.getElementsById('div1').style.backgroundColor = green;
      var dataString = 'name='+name+'&last_name='+last_name;
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:dataString,
        url:'demo.php',
        success:function(data) {
          alert(data);
        }
      });

        }   </script>
            </head>
            <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
     <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
     <input type="submit" name="Update" id="update" value="Update" onclick="my();" />
    </form>
<div id="div1" style="width:300px;height: 50px;background-color: yellow;" >
 </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php

    include('conn.php');
     if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
      $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
      echo $name;
      $insert = "insert into ajaxsave values('$name','$last_name')";// Do Your Insert Query
      if(mysql_query($insert)) {
       echo "Success";
      } else {
       echo "Cannot Insert";
      }
    }?>
```

**demo.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div2" style="width:300px;height: 50px;background-color: yellow;" >
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here i want when i submit form  them div color should change which is in demo.html
where i am wrong in this code

and how can i achieve my goal

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: is the jQuery library included??

Comment: you need to add JQuery library,

Comment: If you have you code like this the Ajax call will return a full HTML page with your JavaScripting and everything, ending with the word 'Success' or 'Cannot Insert'. If you just want the reply from PHP you'll need a separate file for that... Also, jQuery isn't loading in this, so you'd be getting an error in your browser's console...

Comment: A case of TMC: `Too much code` in one page. You have to create another PHP script to handle the `MYSQL` coding and echoes

Comment: which jquery library should i include

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> add this before your my() function

Comment: Your form is right now getting posted to same page without making the ajax call. Is it your case like you want to make an ajax call to `demo.php` and make the form to post to itself? Both actions are required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### changes you need to make:

1. add jquery as a dependency as you are using `$.ajax` utility function which is provided by Jquery.
2. As you are using Jquery, you could use its selectors for getting values of elements and binding functions to dom elements. I have commented it in the source code.
3. You are using a form with a submit button and executing the ajax call on click of it. But you need to prevent the page from submitting the form by preventing the default behavior of the submit button. Refer `event.preventDefault();`
4. Move the php ajax response part to the top and call `exit()` once your response is complete. Else your ajax response will include the whole page html source also.

.

```
 <?php

include('conn.php');
if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $insert = "insert into ajaxsave values('$name','$last_name')";// Do Your Insert Query
    if(mysql_query($insert)) {
        echo "Success";     
    } else {
        echo "Cannot Insert";
    }
    //Call exit as your ajax response ends here. You dont need the html source along with it.
    exit();
}
    
?>
 
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="Update" id="update" value="Update" />
        </form>
        <div id="div1" style="width:300px;height: 50px;background-color: yellow;" >
        </div>
        <!-- include jquery dependeny before your js code block -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>       
        
        $("#update").on("click",function(event) {
            
            //Prevent Default submit button behavour. Prevent the form from submission. 
            event.preventDefault();
            // using Jquery selectors for better readability of code. 
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
            $("#last_name").css("background-color","green");
            
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:{name:name,last_name:last_name,Update:true},
                url:'demo.php',
                success:function(data) {
                  alert(data);
                }
            });
            
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: div color is not getting change

Comment: did u try `$("#last_name").css("background-color","green");`?

Comment: `$("#last_name").css({"background-color":"green"});` also would work.

Comment: how can i change color of div  if it is in another file

Comment: you mean div is in another html page?

Comment: Then you have to include js code in that page. Not here.

Comment: How i did not understand could u tell me

Comment: i am using like this but not workig   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>
   $("#div1").css("background-color","green");
   </script>

Comment: exactly i want when i submit value then div color shoul change which is in  another file

Comment: hey is it like when u submit the form and make ajax call in `demo.php`, you need the div color to change in another page called `demo.html`? I guess its not possible. As there is no way to manipulate dom in another page from a javascript in one page.

Comment: what can i do for this any idea

Comment: is it your exact requirement - When you make an ajax request in one page, then you need to change the background color of a div in another? i am asking again because it doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: my requirement is  when i insert  new value in db then div color should change  which is in another  file  thats it  if it is possible without ajax or with ajax

Answer (score 0):

You send two parameters in "dataString" variable, and then in php check undefined variable "Update"

So, just replace string

```
if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
```

And add this line to  tag

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```